# Say error on Bash on Windows

Tags: windows, bash, command-line

The say command doesn't work in Bash on Windows 10. I installed it but when I try a simple

```
say "hello"
```

I go these errors :

```
say[] No local time zone specified
say[] Using time zone with absolute offset 0
say[] connect attempt failed - =
say : Uncaught exception NSPortTimeoutException reason : root proxy request
```

Comment: does everything else work about `bash on Windows 10` ? (Did you have a good install otherwise)? Good luck.

Comment: not everything is working but a lots of things are. It was installed during the last windows update (anniversary)

Comment: Is `say` supposed to work out of the box on bash on Windows 10? It wouldn't work on bash on Linux, because `say` is a OSX utility and not a bash command.

Answer (score 1):

To fix the time zone errors I ran

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
```

and chose the correct time zone. I am still working to resolve the nsporttimeoutexception.